# An Asp.net SPA aurelia project.. I have added a module to package.json and to webpack but it cant find it

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, aurelia

I have set up an aurelia project using Asp.net Core. It works in the basic format but I decided to add the module aurelia-api to the project.

Its been added to the package.json and thats fine.

I also added it to the webpack.config.vendor.js file.

Once I run this I am getting the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unable to find module with ID: aurelia-api
at WebpackLoader.<anonymous> (boot.ts:26)
at step (boot.ts:26)
at Object.next (boot.ts:26)
at boot.ts:26
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at 74.__awaiter (boot.ts:26)
at WebpackLoader.74.WebpackLoader._import (boot.ts:26)
at WebpackLoader.<anonymous> (boot.ts:26)
at step (boot.ts:26)
at Object.next (boot.ts:26)
```

I have no idea why webpack cant find the module even though I have it in the package.json - here it is:

```
 {
  "name": "Jobsledger.API",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "aurelia-api": "^3.1.1",
    "aurelia-authentication": "^3.7.0",
    "aurelia-bootstrapper": "^2.0.1",
    "aurelia-fetch-client": "^1.0.1",
    "aurelia-framework": "^1.1.0",
    "aurelia-loader-webpack": "^2.0.0",
    "aurelia-pal": "^1.3.0",
    "aurelia-router": "^1.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "fetch": "^1.1.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.0",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "aurelia-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.5",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "ts-loader": "^2.0.3",
    "typescript": "^2.2.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "^2.3.3",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0"
  }
}
```

As you can see aurelia-api is there.  Not sure why this cant be found?

Here is my Webpack.config.vender.js file as well..

```
        var path = require('path');
    var webpack = require('webpack');
    var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
    var extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');

    module.exports = ({ prod } = {}) => {
        const isDevBuild = !prod;

        return [{
            stats: { modules: false },
            resolve: {
                extensions: ['.js']
            },
            module: {
                loaders: [
                    { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
                    { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, loader: extractCSS.extract([isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize']) }
                ]
            },
            entry: {
                vendor: [
                    'aurelia-api',
                    'aurelia-authentication',
                    'aurelia-event-aggregator',
                    'aurelia-fetch-client',
                    'aurelia-framework',
                    'aurelia-history-browser',
                    'aurelia-logging-console',
                    'aurelia-pal-browser',
                    'aurelia-polyfills',
                    'aurelia-route-recognizer',
                    'aurelia-router',
                    'aurelia-templating-binding',
                    'aurelia-templating-resources',
                    'aurelia-templating-router',
                    'bootstrap',
                    'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
                    'jquery'
                ],
            },
            output: {
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist'),
                publicPath: 'dist/',
                filename: '[name].js',
                library: '[name]_[hash]',
            },
            plugins: [
                extractCSS,
                new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
                new webpack.DllPlugin({
                    path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                    name: '[name]_[hash]'
                })
            ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
                new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ compress: { warnings: false } })
            ])
        }]
    };
```

Comment: That did the trick... I was playing with the same modules and ran into the same (sic!) problem. using `.plugin(PLATFORM...` worked for me. You should sonsider passing your command as the proposed answer.